# CMake: Can't link simple project that uses shared zlib wrapper library

Tags: c++, cmake, zlib, libzip

In my situation I have two CMake projects (built using MSYS Makefiles if that matters):

1. One is a shared library that uses Zlib and Libzip to provide zipping functionality to the library user, let's call it *mylib*.
2. Another is an app that uses *mylib* to do some zipping stuff. It doesn't have to worry about Zlib, Libzip or anything. Let's call it *app*.

I have created a bare-bones example below that demonstrates the bizarre issue I'm having. Simply put, *app* refuses to link when running *make*, but only if some Libzip code is left uncommented in *mylib* (which compiles and links fine, no matter what).

Zlib and Libzip source code is located in C:/Dev/Libs.

***lib/CMakeLists.txt***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

# Set project
project(mylib)
set(LIBS_DIR "C:/Dev/Libs")

# Add mylib sources
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS "src/*.cpp")
add_library(mylib SHARED ${SRCS})

# Add Zlib
set(ZLIB_ROOT "${LIBS_DIR}/zlib-1.2.11")
include_directories(${ZLIB_ROOT})
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC ${ZLIB_ROOT})
file(GLOB ZLIB_SRCS "${ZLIB_ROOT}/*.c")
add_library(zlib STATIC ${ZLIB_SRCS})

# Add Libzip
set(LIBZIP_ROOT "${LIBS_DIR}/libzip-1.1.3")
include_directories("${LIBZIP_ROOT}/lib")
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC "${LIBZIP_ROOT}/lib")
file(GLOB LIBZIP_SRCS "${LIBZIP_ROOT}/lib/*.c")
add_library(libzip STATIC ${LIBZIP_SRCS})

set(LIBS_LINK    zlib libzip)
set(LIBS_INSTALL zlib libzip)
set(LIBS_EXPORT  zlib libzip)
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC ${LIBS_LINK})

# https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/
# Define headers for this library. PUBLIC headers are used for
# compiling the library, and will be added to consumers' build
# paths.
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE src)

# 'make install' to the correct locations (provided by GNUInstallDirs).
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS mylib ${LIBS_INSTALL} EXPORT mylibConfig
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})  # This is for Windows
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# This makes the project importable from the install directory
# Put config file in per-project dir (name MUST match), can also
# just go into 'cmake'.
install(EXPORT mylibConfig DESTINATION share/mylib/cmake)

# This makes the project importable from the build directory
export(TARGETS mylib ${LIBS_EXPORT} FILE mylibConfig.cmake)
```

***lib/src/lib.hpp***

```
#pragma once

namespace lib
{
    int func();
}
```

***lib/src/lib.cpp***

```
#include "lib.hpp"

#define ZIP_STATIC
#include "zip.h"

int lib::func()
{
    zip_source_t *src;
    zip_error_t error;
    src = zip_source_buffer_create(0, 1, 0, &error);

    return 10;
}
```

***app/CMakeLists.txt***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(app)

# Add app sources
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(app ${SRCS})

# Add mylib
set(mylib_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../lib")
find_package(mylib REQUIRED)
configure_file("${mylib_DIR}/libmylib.dll" "libmylib.dll" COPYONLY)
target_link_libraries(app mylib)
```

***app/src/app.hpp***

```
#pragma once
#include <lib.hpp>
```

***app/src/app.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "app.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << lib::func() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output from building *mylib*

```
$ make
[ 13%] Built target zlib
[ 98%] Built target libzip
Scanning dependencies of target mylib
[ 99%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/lib.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libmylib.dll
[100%] Built target mylib
```

Output from building *app*

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target app
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/app.dir/src/app.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable app.exe
CMakeFiles/app.dir/objects.a(app.cpp.obj):app.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `lib::func()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [app.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I comment `src = zip_source_buffer_create(0, 1, 0, &error);` in ***lib/src/lib.cpp***, rebuild and then rebuild *app*:

```
$ make
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Dev/Builds/cmaketest/app
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable app.exe
[100%] Built target app

$ ./app
10
```

Which yields the expected result.

The issue must lie in the CMakeLists of *app*, since *mylib* builds fine without any linking errors. Or am I adding zlib/libzip incorrectly in *mylib*? I need to link to them statically and I couldn't get it to work with `find_package`.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't build on Windows, but don't dlls require an extra file with the list of exported symbols (memory says mylib.dll.a, but it's been years).  I don't see the `__declspec(dllexport)` stuff that enables those symbols.

Comment: That was it! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working after copying over the .dll.a file as well:

```
configure_file("${mylib_DIR}/libmylib.dll.a" "libmylib.dll.a" COPYONLY)
```

and prefixing all my methods in *lib* with the following:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```